# Exibir diálogo de confirmação antes de fechar aba do tabview primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em jsf  que preciso trabalhar com abas
(parecido com o chrome). Para tal, estou usando o componente tabview do primefaces que vem sendo bem útil até o momento.

O problema é que necessito exibir um diálogo de confirmação de fechamento antes do fechamento de uma determinada aba.
Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Segue abaixo o xhtml até o momento:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="frm">
            <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" />
            <p:tabView id="abas">
                <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{beanAba.fecharAba}" />
                <p:tab title="Aba 1" closable="true">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                        <h:outputText value="Alguma Coisa 1" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Aba 2" closable="true">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                        <h:outputText value="Alguma Coisa 2 " />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Aba 3" closable="true">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">

                        <h:outputText value="Alguma Coisa 3" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>

            <p:confirmDialog global="true" id="dlg" >
                <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"   />
                <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"/>
            </p:confirmDialog>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

E aqui está meu Bean:

```
package com.controller.aba;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;


@Named(value = "beanAba")
@ViewScoped
public class BeanAba implements Serializable {

    public void fecharAba() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesContext fContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();


        context.execute("PF('dlg').show();");


        fContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Aba Removida!"));
        context.update("frm:message");
    }
}
```

Comment: Aparentemente não é possivel fazer tal ação sem alterar o código do primefaces. https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=41298 e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833839/confirmdialog-on-tabclose-event.

Comment: Como eu poderia realizar essa alteração no código do prime?